# Returning the value from the cursor in function in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, function, return, cursor

I wrote a function containing a cursor which returns True / False values. Is the below code is correct? Will the output be displayed as 'True' in this case? I haven't used any Loop/End Loop.

```
FUNCTION get_fruit_value(pn_code in NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
AS

nvalue     varchar2;
vfru_name  varchar2(100);

CURSOR C1
IS
SELECT fruit_name from grocery where grocery_code = pn_code;
-- here output has 4 values :  **fruit_name = Apple, Orange, Banana, Kivi**

BEGIN
 OPEN C1;
 FETCH C1 into vfru_name;

   if vfru_name = 'Apple' then
    nvalue ='True';
   else 
    nvalue ='False';
  end if;

CLOSE C1;

RETURN nvalue;

END get_fruit_value;
```

Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It looks as if you only expect 1 row returned from the cursor.  So why use a cursor at all?  Why not a single SELECT?  And you say "Will the output be displayed as 'True' in this case?".  What happened when you tested it for yourself?  "Please do needful"  What is "the needful"?  SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens..I got the answer. That means loop is needed to get multiple values.  I couldn't test it myself as I lost sql developer tool connection.

Comment: Yes, the entire purpose of a cursor is to grab multiple rows, then loop through them, FETCHing  one at a time for further processing on each row in turn.  The entire purpose of a function is to return a single value.

Comment: You are missing some colons too.  "nvalue = 'True'" won't compile. You need ":="

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use FOR LOOP statement (more information: https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor-for-loop/)

With your example:

```
FUNCTION get_fruit_value(pn_code in NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
AS

nvalue     varchar2;
vfru_name  varchar2(100);

CURSOR C1
IS
SELECT fruit_name from grocery where grocery_code = pn_code;
-- here output has 4 values :  **fruit_name = Apple, Orange, Banana, Kivi**

BEGIN

 FOR record IN C1
 LOOP

   if record.fruit_name = 'Apple' then
    nvalue ='True';
   else 
    nvalue ='False';
  end if;

END LOOP;     

RETURN nvalue;

END get_fruit_value;
```

I hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to what's being said, `SELECT` will return only one row so there's no need for `LOOP`. Actually, there's no need for `CURSOR` either. I presume you used it to avoid `NO_DATA_FOUND`, which is - in my opinion - wrong, as it only causes confusion. A `SELECT` with `EXCEPTION` handler would do.

Here's what I mean: sample table first:

```
SQL> select * From grocery;

GROCERY_CODE FRUIT_
------------ ------
           1 Orange
           2 Banana
           3 Apple
           4 Kivi
```

Function: its purpose (according to what you wrote) is to find out whether certain `grocery_code` represents *apples*.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_is_apple (par_grocery_code in grocery.grocery_code%type)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(10) := 'False';
  5  begin
  6    select 'True'
  7      into retval
  8      from grocery g
  9      where g.grocery_code = par_grocery_code
 10        and g.fruit_name = 'Apple';
 11
 12    return retval;
 13  exception
 14    when no_data_found then
 15      return retval;
 16  end f_is_apple;
 17  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select level as grocery_code,
  2         f_is_apple(level) result
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 4;

GROCERY_CODE RESULT
------------ ----------
           1 False
           2 False
           3 True            --> only code 3 is "apple"
           4 False

SQL>
```